# Get_MLDB_Full_Descriptor assertion failed when using AKAZE on OpenCV {Python}

Tags: python, opencv, feature-detection

I'm using the AKAZE constructor on `Python 3.8` & `OpenCV 4.4.0.44` from `PIP`.

I'm trying to combine different parameters in the constructor, and planning to execute them on a dataset.
The constructor works fine with its default parameters.

See the code and the different values passed:

```python
    # [ options is the argparser ]

    grayscale_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    grayscale_image = cv2.resize(grayscale_image, (256, 256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    if mask is not None:
        mask = cv2.resize(mask, (256, 256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        mask = (mask == 0).astype(np.uint8) * 255

    # Options of the constructor
    #    - descriptor_type          Type of the extracted descriptor: DESCRIPTOR_KAZE,
    #                               DESCRIPTOR_KAZE_UPRIGHT, DESCRIPTOR_MLDB or DESCRIPTOR_MLDB_UPRIGHT.
    #    - descriptor_size          Size of the descriptor in bits. 0 -> Full size
    #    - descriptor_channels      Number of channels in the descriptor (1, 2, 3)
    #    - threshold                Detector response threshold to accept point
    #    - nOctaves                 Maximum octave evolution of the image
    #    - nOctaveLayers            Default number of sublevels per scale level
    #    - diffusivity              Diffusivity type. DIFF_PM_G1, DIFF_PM_G2, DIFF_WEICKERT or DIFF_CHARBONNIER

    # Assuring type is the expected for each one
    descriptor_size = int(options.ak_desc_size)  ## 0 = full size
    descriptor_type = int(options.ak_desc_type)  ## 5 or 4 or 3 or 2 descriptor
    threshold = float(options.ak_threshold)      ## variable (0.001)
    channels = int(options.ak_desc_chan)         ## with 3 works, not with 1 or 2
    num_octaves = int(options.ak_num_octav)      ## 4
    octave_layers = int(options.ak_oct_layer)    ## 4
    difussivity = int(options.ak_diffusivt)      ## 0..3
    akaze = cv2.AKAZE_create(descriptor_size=descriptor_size,
                             descriptor_type=descriptor_type,
                             threshold=threshold,
                             descriptor_channels=channels,
                             nOctaves=num_octaves,
                             nOctaveLayers=octave_layers,
                             diffusivity=difussivity)
    keypoints = akaze.detect(grayscale_image, mask=mask)
```

When I'm executing a combination of parameters with `descriptor_channels == 2 or ==1`  it's trhowing the following exception:

> `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) /tmp/pip-req-build-6amqbhlx/opencv/modules/features2d/src/kaze/AKAZEFeatures.cpp:1986: error: (-215:Assertion failed) dpos == 486 in function 'Get_MLDB_Full_Descriptor'`

I've reviewed the [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.4.0/d8/d30/classcv_1_1AKAZE.html) but I don't know what am I missing.

Any guidance on what might be the error?

Comment: I looked into the implementation of OpenCV. Did you try to set `descriptor_type` to `DESCRIPTOR_MLDB_UPRIGHT` or `5` and then change the number of channels to 1 or 2? Seems like this value is only relevant if you set the descriptor type to `DESCRIPTOR_MLDB_UPRIGHT`. Give me feedback if it works and I would post an answer.

Comment: Hi @Grillteller. The issues with descriptor_type different than 4,5 don't work
This is the combination of methods:
[type = 5, channel = 2 ] = FAIL
[type = 5, channel = 1 ] = FAIL
[type = 4, channel = 2 ] = FAIL
[type = 4, channel = 1 ] = FAIL with message: corrupted unsorted chunks

[type = 3, channel = 3 ] = PASS - No exception
[type = 3, channel = 2 ] = PASS - No exception
[type = 2, channel = 1 ] = PASS - No exception


I understand that descriptor_type{4,5} only works with descriptor_channels = 3